# How do i list all child terms that share the same parent term? But on "child term" page?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 9

Let's say I have the following taxonomy (a 3-level hierarchy).

- Acura

  - Integra

    - Hatchback 1991
    - Hatchback 1995
    - Hatchback 2000

If I am on the last term of this hierarchy, for example *Hatchback 1991*, how do I display all other specific models that belong to its parent (*Hatchback 1995* and *Hatchback 2000*)?

**Probably Taxonomy Term Siblings.**

Comment: Adding a relationship to the parent term and creating a contextual filter using it is the standard way to solve this - if it's not working for you please edit the question to provide full details of what you're trying so people can see what you're working with

Comment: I don't know if I spoke correctly, but I need this:

On the child term page I need a list of other child terms that belong to his parent term and possibly to his grandparent.

Comment: That will probably need custom code, I don't think out of the box Views will be able to build a query that complicated with the UI

Comment: If I'm on the "child term page", then views can't show child terms that share the same parent? Strange.

Comment: Yeah it can do that, see my original comment. You added grandparents afterwards, though. I suspect that will complicate the SQL query to the point the UI wouldn’t be able to build it. Prove me wrong though!

Comment: Does this help? https://www.drupal.org/node/1084402#comment-9932710

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. At least not in Drupal 9.